# Why BarChart3D plot of Mathematica 9 is not working similar to Mathematica 7 version?

Tags: plotting

Mathematica 7

```
Needs["BarCharts`"]

BarChart3D[{{1, 6, 8}, {2, 7, 1}, {3, 1, 4}}]
```

[image]

While in Mathematica 9 it is not plotting in this manner. Please help me to plot this fig. in Mathematica 9.

Comment: @santosh try the ChartLayout -> "Grid" option..well, not exactly, but you'll get your cube

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BarChart3D[Transpose[{{1, 6, 8}, {2, 7, 1}, {3, 1, 4}}], 
 ChartLayout -> "Grid"]
```

gives similar chart.

Comment: you're fast... ;)